# How do i found developers groups to let they build my own startup?

Tags: web-development, development, startup

As for the title, i would like to meet some developers groups to pay them to build startups, doesn't matter where they are located, just they should speak english.

does anyone knows how can i found them and where?

thanks!

Comment: :/ off topic ..?

Comment: It's pretty off topic and it's a discussion question so it was always going to get closed I'm afraid.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles i'm afraid maybe Jhon didn't understand we are on webmaster q&a site, web masters works and searchs also for collaborators, i didn't asked if is there any collaborator, i just wanted to know where(links) to find them , sorry but i don't think it's off topic :P

Comment: i can ask where to find site to ask where to find collaborators :D

Comment: You might try the onStartups stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on where you live, but for London and most large western cities [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/) usually has a good selection of weekly and monthly groups.

Comment: well seems good there is not somenthing more specific on the web? this seems to be  a "generic group maker" :P

Comment: @Ispuk It is, it's designed to promote groups by establishing a large installed base for new groups to draw from and easy tools for managing group events. You'll find most of the good tech groups in London on there.